# Dotless i showing with ASCII code for dotted i in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding, ascii

I have the following entry in my SQL Server database:
Tashızo Spırıts

The following code:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(NAME,11,1)...
```

Returns: ı

The following code returns:

```
SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(NAME,11,1))...
```

Returns: 105

The record is NOT returned using the like command searching for i or ı.

This is easy to fix, but I want to know how it has occurred that I have a dotless i in my sql database with the ASCII value for the dotted i.

Comment: `Yoshıno Spırıts` is the NAME value or your db name?

Comment: The field is called Name. The value is Yoshıno Spırıts

Comment: what encoding are you using ?

Comment: `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: I am using NVARCHAR

Comment: Then `ASCII` will do you no good, do a `SELECT UNICODE(SUBSTRING(NAME,11,1))...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASCII() just have no codespace to represent unicode chars. Use UNICODE() to see real value.

```
declare @v nvarchar(100) = N'Yoshıno Spırıts';
declare @c nvarchar(1)= SUBSTRING(@v,11,1)
select ASCII(@c), UNICODE(@c), char(ASCII(@c)), nchar(UNICODE(@c))
```

Comment: Thanks, it's 305, which is indeed a unicode dotless i. Just need to find out how/why a user would type it in now :)